# How to reach and add new row to web server database which made in Django framework?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, webserver

I am trying to create a web server which has Django framework and I am struggling with outer world access to server. While saying outer world I am trying to say a python program that created out of Django framework and only connects it from local PC which has only Internet connection. I can't figured it out how can I do this.

I am building this project in my local host, so I create the "outer world python program" outside of the project file. I think this simulation is proper.

I am so new in this web server/Django field. So maybe I am missing an essential part. If this happened here  I'm sorry but I need an answer and I think it is possible to do.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django generated fields in database are just standard fields. The tables are named like 'applicationname'_'modelname', you are free to do requests to the database directly, without django.

If you want to do it through django, your outer program can request a web page from your web server, and deal with it. (You may want to take a look at RESTs frameworks)

Comment: Thanks for answering! In first paragraph, "you are free to do requests to the database directly, without django.", is the "requests" here corresponds to the requests/urllib-like modules which is simple "requests.get()" request from a web page? In addition thanks for suggestion on RESts frameworks.

Comment: Im sorry its not, the "request" you talk about is the one i was talking about in the second part. The first request i am talking about is SQL queries, wich are not related to python or django. (There are modules in python to request an SQL database if you want to do it this way)

Comment: Maybe read this https://realpython.com/python-sql-libraries, it show examples in python to use the SQL databases